# Fullscreen image

Tags: image-processing, windows-phone-8, stream

Im developing on WP8... I want to render an image in fullscreen size... obviously i do not the size of the screen...
I try to explain another problem... I must resize the image (image are about 2000x1400px and the screen is about 800x4450px).. but i dont really want to resize the real dimension... i just want the dimension remain the same but i want to see the full image (no cutted)

Here the code i have written

```
System.Windows.Size dimensions = App.RootFrame.RenderSize;

WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap((int)dimensions.Width,(int)dimensions.Height);
wb.LoadJpeg(myStreamPhoto);
wb.Invalidate();

ImgChosenPhoto.Source = wb;
```

I achieve the goal in this way... the image is not really resized but, however, i can see the full image on screen.. so what's the problem?

If I open the image directly from my app everything works! If i open the photo from the photo library and select my app i obtain an exception (same code is runned).. the exception is:

```
Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

Comment: Actually, it seems that you have two different problems. Here's a little suggestion for the first one: in your XAML `<Image x:Name="ImgChosenPhoto" Stretch="Fill"/>` and then, in you c# code, `ImgChosenPhoto.Source = myStreamPhoto`. Please note that this isn't the best solution because it still loads the full image and this will take some RAM, so you may be interested in `BitmapImage`'s `DecodedPixelHeight` and `DecodedPixelWidth` properties. Change `Fill` to `UniformToFill` if you want to preserve ratio. Let me know if you see the whole fullscreen image

Comment: No it has not worked... In my XAML i have `<Image x:Name="ImgChosenPhoto" Stretch="Uniform"/>`.. I think the problem is that if I open photo from library it is read-only, so i cannot use a `WriteableBitmap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved in this way

```
System.Windows.Size dimensions = ResolutionHelper.ScreenResolution;

BitmapImage wb = new BitmapImage();
wb.SetSource(myStreamPhoto);

ImgChosenPhoto.Source = wb;

ImgChosenPhoto.Height = (int)dimensions.Height;
ImgChosenPhoto.Width = (int)dimensions.Width;
```

Comment: If you use classes which are not default in Windows Phone, please explain from there you've got the. E.g. the class ResolutionHelper comes from here i guess: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, im sorry... the class ResolutionHelper is exactly the same you have linked.